# HTML table not rendering correctly in IE9

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer-9, rendering, html-table

Really weird one, this.

I'm using an `asp:Repeater` to create an HTML table, like so:

**Markup:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRpt" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="myGrd" border="0" style="cursor:pointer;width:100%;  background-color:white;" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr onclick="criteria.rowClicked(this);">
            <td style="border:solid 1px black;">
                <asp:Literal ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </td>
            <td style="border:solid 1px black;width:200px;">
                <asp:Literal ID="lblRange" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none;" >
                <asp:Literal ID="lblMisc" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody> </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**VB:**

```
    Public Sub populateGrid(ByVal ds As DataSet)
        'ds is just made from a simple select query
        myRpt.DataSource = ds
        myRpt.DataBind()
    End Sub

 Private Sub myRpt_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles myRpt.ItemDataBound
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Dim lblName As Literal = e.Item.FindControl("lblName")
            Dim lblRange As Literal = e.Item.FindControl("lblRange")
            Dim lblMisc As Literal = e.Item.FindControl("lblMisc")

            lblName.Text = "<font style='font-size:10pt; font-family:arial;'>" & Trim(e.Item.DataItem("Name")) & "</font>"
            lblRange.Text = "<font style='font-size:10pt; font-family:arial;'>" & Trim(e.Item.DataItem("Range")) & "</font>"
            lblMisc.Text = "<font style='font-size:10pt; font-family:arial;'>" & Trim(e.Item.DataItem("Miscellaneous")) & "</font>"
        End If
    End Sub
```

This displays fine in Firefox and Chrome, and most of the time in IE. However sometimes for larger tables (50+ rows) IE behaves strangely. It appears to add a blank cell...

[image]

...but there's nothing in the HTML- I've checked using the developer tools. The incorrect row has identical markup to the correct rows, except for the cell text. Whatsmore, if I delete the incorrect row, the one above it starts displaying wrong instead.

Please can someone suggest why on earth IE is rendering it like this, and what I can do to stop it.

Comment: It looks like this is an HTML/CSS/IE problem, not related to ASP. Any chance you could replicate the issue in a JS Fiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I've copied the HTML into jsfiddle. Strangely, it seems to render ok there.

Comment: Just a thought - is IE rendering the page in Quirks Mode? If you open the Developer Tools on the page, what are the Browser Mode and Document Mode reported on the right of the menu bar?

Comment: Browser Mode: IE9. Document Mode: IE9 standards

Comment: How are you actually binding your values to the repeater as I don't see any eval() s or anything?

Comment: @Bex Good point. Sorry. I've added that to the post.

Comment: Could it be that the string-data you're inserting contains characters like <, >, ', " (quotes) so the resulting html is malformed?

Comment: @Warappa. No, it doesn't. Besides, that wouldn't explan the erratic behaviour of the bug (remove the problem row, and another goes wrong instead).

Comment: Can you please post resulting HTML of your page? I mean take source in IE.

Comment: It would be very easy to help you, if you could provide resulting HTML of your page....

Comment: The one you've sent looks really well on my machine (IE9 also).

Comment: Can you show the complete HTML with CSS and JS included?

Comment: Have you tried running it on an other PC? I've seen some strange thing happens with people that have malware.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug with IE9 on rendering large tables.  The problem was resolved when removing white space between table def opening and closing tags eg. `</td><td>`

[MSDN discussion on IE 9 rendering](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/iewebdevelopment/thread/e6f49d52-ec3f-47c5-802e-b80d1a58ed39)

Comment: +1 I am sure this is a BUG on IE9. I've seen this error before and ONLY IE9 exhibits this behavior.

Comment: +1 Such a headache, but such a simple (albeit weird) solution. Bounty awarded- thanks!

Comment: @Urbycoz, could put the solution of the problem, because the link "http://goo.gl/uhOSk" is broken

Comment: also if you have a comment following a td or th closing element make sure there are no spaces between the </td> and <!-- -->

Answer (score 3):

This is a known IE9 issue, you can fix this by putting the following code somewhere in your HTML page:

```
$(function() {
    var browser = $.browser;
    if ( browser.msie && browser.version.slice(0,3) == "9.0" ) {
        $('table').each(function(index) {
                var replace = $(this).html().replace(/td>\s+<td/g,'td><td'); 
                $(this).html(replace);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a huge table that expanded when a Click event occurred. Happened only in IE9, all was fine in IE8, IE10, Chrome etc.

The above solution failed for me, as well as others answers of the same kind.

I solved it this way:

I added borders to the table and it was clear that the HTML was not correct. Either some colspan was missing or the cells needed `&nbsp;` or could have been anything.

I also noticed that now, with the tables `border=1` attribute, the problem with the Click-expanding was gone.

So I put a class `xltable` to the table and put `.xltable td {border:0px solid white;}` in my css.

My code is still not "valid" but it works.