# asp:Gridview one Row is shifted from the others

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

We have an asp:GridView. On the RowDataBound we set the Buttons etc. depending on the Data, the User-rights etc. etc.
It appears, that exactly one Row seems to be out of sync:
Every cell of this row is shifted by one, but at the left side, there is no additional field (Tested with the IE F12 function). Funny enought this, happens only at one exact Row AND only at IE. I thought, probably the data has some special characters, which get interpreted as delimiter, but this isnt the case as well.

Sadly I cant upload a picture, probably you see what I mean. Is there a known Bug for IE and Gridview, which can cause such stuff? Since the data seem to fit and there are no hidden fields etc. on the Page, I cant get another explanation.

Thanks in advance and a good start in the week!

Matthias

Edit: Got it! It's really a IE9 bug in HTML-Tables. See: [HTML table not rendering correctly in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174041/html-table-not-rendering-correctly-in-ie9)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML table not rendering correctly in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174041/html-table-not-rendering-correctly-in-ie9)